# Intersecting shapes in edit mode to create single shape

Tags: edit-mode

For example use the olympics circles logo. Add 7 circles like in that logo. Now how do I make it into a one object like this:
[image]

This is an ugly manual example tho. How do I get intersections with vertices that follows the shape 100%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an addon called *TinyCAD*, which I think is implemented in Blender by default, so you just have to activate it in the *Preferences*.

Once activated, select all your vertices in *Edit* mode, then right click > *TinyCAD* > *XALL Intersect Selected Edges*. It will create a common vertex everywhere the edges are crossing. Then you just need to remove the doubles with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*, and remove all the inner vertices.

[image]